# Scrape Glassdoor data with selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, cloudflare

I'm scrape the reviews data from glassdoor, and I test my code succesfully when I first finish the edit, but when I need to use them for large scale scrape, it always have a verify from cloudflare, and how should I passby it, here is my code, especially function:

```
import csv
import time
import random
import logging
from selenium import webdriver as wd
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

DEFAULT_URL = 'https://www.glassdoor.com/Reviews/index.htm?overall_rating_low=3.5&page=1&locId=1140588&locType=C'
COMPANY_NAMES = ['Super Microsoft Technology', 'NICE Holdings']

USERNAME = 'username'
PASSWORD = 'password'

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(ch)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(lineno)d:%(filename)s(%(process)d) - %(message)s')
ch.setFormatter(formatter)

def sign_in():
    url = 'https://www.glassdoor.com/profile/login_input.htm'
    browser.get(url)

    email_field = browser.find_element('css selector', 'input[autocomplete="username"]')
    email_field.send_keys(USERNAME)
    time.sleep(3)
    next_button = browser.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="InlineLoginModule"]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/form/div[2]/button')
    next_button.click()

    time.sleep(3)

    password_field = browser.find_element('css selector', 'input[autocomplete="current-password"]')
    submit_btn = browser.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="InlineLoginModule"]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/form/div[2]/button')

    password_field.send_keys(PASSWORD)
    submit_btn.click()

    time.sleep(3)
    browser.get(DEFAULT_URL)

def navigate_to_reviews(company_name):
    browser.get(DEFAULT_URL)

    time.sleep(random.uniform(1, 3))

    search_field = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#companyAutocomplete-companyDiscover-employerSearch')))
    search_field.send_keys(company_name)

    search_button = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.gd-ui-button[data-test="company-search-button"]')))
    search_button.click()

    time.sleep(random.uniform(1, 3))

    search_results = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.d-flex.flex-column.my-std.mb-sm-0.css-1b46kjl a')))

    if search_results:
        first_result = search_results[0]
        first_result.click()

        time.sleep(random.uniform(1, 3))

        WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[@data-test="ei-nav-reviews-link"]')))

        reviews_cell = browser.find_element('xpath', '//a[@data-test="ei-nav-reviews-link"]')
        reviews_path = reviews_cell.get_attribute('href')

        browser.get(reviews_path)
        time.sleep(random.uniform(1, 3))

        WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[starts-with(@id, "empReview")]')))

        reviews = []

        while True:
            review_elements = browser.find_elements('xpath', '//*[starts-with(@id, "empReview")]')
            for review_element in review_elements:
                review = extract_pros_cons(review_element)
                reviews.append(review)

            next_button = browser.find_elements('xpath', '//button[@data-test="next-page" and not(@disabled)]')
            if not next_button:
                break

            next_button[0].click()
            time.sleep(random.uniform(1, 3))
            WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[starts-with(@id, "empReview")]')))

        return reviews

    else:
        print("No search results found.")
        return []

def get_browser():
    logger.info('Configuring browser')
    chrome_options = wd.EdgeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument('log-level=3')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--incognito')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-setuid-sandbox')
    chrome_options.add_argument('user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/537.36')
    browser = wd.Edge(options=chrome_options)
    return browser

def extract_pros_cons(review_element):
    pros_element = review_element.find_element('css selector', '.review-details_pro__rMvtX span[data-test="review-text-pros"]')
    cons_element = review_element.find_element('css selector', '.review-details_con__9IvnD span[data-test="review-text-cons"]')
    date_element = review_element.find_element('css selector', '.timestamp_reviewDate__fBGY6')
    employee_status_element = review_element.find_element('css selector', '.review-details_employeeDetails__LuKJ7')
    overall_rating_element = review_element.find_element('css selector', '.review-details_overallRating__Rxhdr')

    show_more_button = review_element.find_elements('css selector', '.review-details_showMoreButton__x_JZx button')

    if show_more_button:
        show_more_button[0].click()
        time.sleep(random.uniform(1, 3))

    pros_text = pros_element.text.strip()
    cons_text = cons_element.text.strip()
    date_text = date_element.text.strip()
    employee_status_text = employee_status_element.text.strip()
    overall_rating_text = overall_rating_element.text.strip()

    return {
        "pros": pros_text,
        "cons": cons_text,
        "date": date_text,
        "employee_status": employee_status_text,
        "overall_rating": float(overall_rating_text)
    }

def write_to_csv(company_name, reviews):
    fieldnames = ['pros', 'cons', 'date', 'employee_status', 'overall_rating']

    filename = f"{company_name}.csv"
    with open(filename, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

        writer.writeheader()
        for review in reviews:
            writer.writerow(review)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    browser = get_browser()
    sign_in()

    for company_name in COMPANY_NAMES:
        reviews = navigate_to_reviews(company_name)
        write_to_csv(company_name, reviews)

    browser.quit()
```

some elements may seems weird but exactly pass my test, and how could I pass the verify to scrape about 1,000 companies's review

a lot thanks for help!!!

Comment: The owner of the website doesn't want bots scraping their website, and they have implemented Cloudflare bot detection to block that. Why do you think you should be entitled to bypass that, against the wishes of the site owner? What you are asking us to do is help you bypass the terms and conditions of the website.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking for help bypassing a website's security.